# how JSONP will work in the behind-the-scenes in cross domain ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am in the initial steps of jQuery AJAX and I am trying to understand how JSONP will help in cross domain communication. Can some body throw some light on this please?

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "",
    method: "",
    data: {},
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](https://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/jsonp-how-does-it-work/) article, it will guide you.

> The idea of JSONP is actually pretty simple: toss a script tag into
>   the DOM with a reference to a resource that returns JSON data. Have
>   the server return said JSON with “padding” (the “P” part of JSONP)
>   that executes a function wrapping the incoming data. In order for this
>   to work properly, the server API must also support JSONP. Typically,
>   the function name is named as the callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

iIt adds a new `<script src="sourceURL"></script>` tag to your DOM (i.e. the HTML you write). Just like if you'd include jQuery by 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
Then, instead of having `$()` or `jQuery()` functions available you can use your JSONP functions like for example `MyCallback()` in your further code.